# Flutter FutureBuilder Tap List Item Extract Index Number

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I need to extract FutureBuilder list item index to edit the list item on another screen MyForm.

In the code below where the snapshot has data, I create the list.

When I tap on a list item, I will go to MyForm screen to edit the list item.

Issue: I need to know the index number of the list item that I tapped on.

On MyForm screen, I want to update the list item using the same index number.

Could you please advise how to extract the list index number.

```
Widget jlist = SizedBox(width: 800, height: 500, child: FutureBuilder<List<Job>?>(future: readAllItems(),builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Job>?> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return ListView.separated(shrinkWrap: true,itemCount: MyFormState.jobs.length,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(height: 100, child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[Text('')],)));
    },separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) => const Divider());
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Job> items = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView.separated(shrinkWrap: true,itemCount: items.length,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(height: 100, child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(title: Text(items[index].Description,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),onTap:() {
        
          //How do I extract the list index number to use on MyForm screen?
                
         MyFormState.myNote.text = items[index].Description;
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyForm()));
         })])));
        },separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) => const Divider());
        }
      else {
        return const Text('No data available');
      }
    }));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index value as parameters  to your next view which is MyForm screen in your case like this :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => MyForm(
                          index: index,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
```

And this is how you can retrieve it from your next view which is MyForm

this is how your constructor should look like

```
const MyForm({
super.key,
required this.index, });
```

This is how you can call the index that you want to use in your code :

```
widget.index,// call depends on what you're going to do with this passed value
```

I hope this can solve your issue

Comment: Hello! Thank You! This is very useful, but in my case, I don't want to use Navigator. First, I want to pick an item from list, do some manipulation. Then, if necessary, I will go to another screen. Is there a way to do this without using Navigator? Thank You

Comment: You can use shared preferences https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences